# Reverse proxying subdomains to different ports on the same machine throws 404

Tags: node.js, reverse-proxy, diet-js, redbird, redwire

I tried my hands on `redbird` like:

```
var proxy = require('redbird')({port: 80});

proxy.register("http://www.example.com", "http://36.154.99.115:3000");
proxy.register("http://abc.example.com", "http://36.154.99.115:3001");
proxy.register("http://xyz.example.com", "http://36.154.99.115:3002");
```

and `redwire` like:

```
var RedWire = require('redwire');
proxy = new RedWire({http: { port: 80 }});

proxy.http("http://www.example.com", "http://36.154.99.115:3000");
proxy.http("http://abc.example.com", "http://36.154.99.115:3001");
proxy.http("http://xyz.example.com", "http://36.154.99.115:3002");
```

I can hit `http://36.154.99.115:3000`, `http://36.154.99.115:3001` and `http://36.154.99.115:3003` to successfully load the respective web pages, but when I try to hit `http://www.example.com`, all I get is `404 host not found`.

I get the following log on my console:

```
{"name":"redbird","hostname":"ip-172-31-23-160","pid":3239,"level":30,"msg":"Proxying www.example.com/ to www.example.com:3000/","time":"2017-02-12T08:07:57.540Z","v":0}
```

which looks like success, but it actually doesn't work...

The servers running on 3000, 3001 and 3002 are using `DietJS` if that matters...

> Note: I tried `proxy.register("http://www.example.com", "http://www.facebook.com")` and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Diet.js* seems to be the issue here, try porting the web-server to *Express.js*.

Alternatively, try creating a sample application with *Express.js* or something relatively generic and try redirecting to it. If that works (which hopefully would), you know what to do.